# How to create an exclusion list for certain rules based on RequestUri on the Azure WAF policy associated with Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

I have a request URL :

> `www.<some-url>.com/submit`

.

I can see that I can create exclusions based on **args, headers** and **cookies** in exclusion lists for the Azure WAF policy, however, I was hoping to create a rule based on the request URI.

[Try Custom rules--> Matchtype: String,  MatchVariable: RequestURI]

Answer (score 0):

In order to create exclusions based on **args, headers** and **cookies** in exclusion lists for the Azure WAF policy we have to create our own **custom rules** or we can use **Managed rules** provided by default.

You can configure an exclusion to apply across all WAF [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/application-gateway-waf-configuration?tabs=portal).

NOTE:
Sometimes WAF rules may block a request that you want to allow for your application. If any site down, disable the rule and retry..

Steps:
[image]

We can add rule like this
[image]